# How to upload a file on click of a button in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

*I have a requirement to upload a zip file with the click of an upload or save button. Then, when the user clicks on the "run" button, the uploaded file should get processed.*

I created a simple form and could write code to upload a file when the submit button was clicked, as shown below.

```py
if request.method=='POST':
   upload_request=UploadFile()
   upload_request.file=request.FILES['file_upload']
   upload_request.save()
```

Template:

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token%}
    <input type="file" required name="file_upload" id="choose_upload_file" value="" accept=".zip,.rar,.7z,.gz,"></br>           
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" value="upload" id="file_upload1">
</form>
```

But how do I have a save functionality (a file should be uploaded) before submitting the form?

I am new to Django. Please give me some insights.

Comment: So you want to upload your file before form is submitted?. If yes then you've to use [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) to upload file here is an [example](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html) learn about [django-ajax](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)